# Custom appointment form is different when opening appointment

Tags: vba, outlook

I have made a custom form region for my appointments in outlook - Which I really would like to use. 
However, I have a problem with implementing it in my outlook.

When I want to schedule a new appointment, it opens up the correct form that I want to use - and works without any issues.

However, the problem occurs when I want to open and see my appointment. Here, it shows some previous published version - Which of cause does not properly work.

**Things I have tried**

I don't remember, that I at any time specified a default form to use upon opening an appointment. But the way it acts, it seems like I did.

- I have tried deleting and republish my form with a different name
- I have tried specifying "When posting to this folder, use" for my calendar

Still, it keeps opening already scheduled appointments with a completely different form, that I made several days ago.

Comment: Do you use VBA to update appointment form controls?

Comment: yep! I have a form control with vba code behind

Comment: Sharing the relevant part of your code may help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every Outlook item has the class name set, so that is how Outlook knows which form should be used to display the item. See [Associate a form region with an Outlook message class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/associating-a-form-region-with-an-outlook-message-class?view=vs-2019) for more information.

Also, you may take a look at the [Assign a custom form to existing Outlook items](https://www.slipstick.com/developer/vba-set-existing-contacts-custom-form/) article.